# Swift 3 NSCache Generic parameter 'KeyType' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

This code worked in Swift 2.x:

```
/// An internal in-memory cache
private var dataCache = NSCache.init()
```

In **Swift 3** it causes compilation error:

```
Generic parameter 'KeyType' could not be inferred
```

Why is that so and how should I refactor this (Migration tool did not pick this up)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

- In the first Swift 3 betas `NSCache` has been changed to `Cache`.
- In the latest betas (currently 5) it has been reverted to `NSCache`.

Anyway `NSCache` is now a generic.

```
public class NSCache<KeyType : AnyObject, ObjectType : AnyObject> : NSObject { ...
```

so the most general syntax is

```
private var dataCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
```

The explicit `init()` is not needed (not even in Swift 2)

Comment: I get: "Use of unresolved identifier 'Cache' " when I try to do that.

Comment: Swift 3 is still beta, there are a few different beta versions and there could be changes from version to version. I updated the answer.

Comment: I am curious why did they revert Cache to NSCache back again in beta5

Comment: I have not downloaded all beta versions, it could be also much earlier than in beta 5, and there are other classes like `(NS)Predicate` and `(NS)SortDescriptor` which have been changed back. Maybe the Objective-C counterparts have also been extended to be compatible.

Comment: @Lukasz I believe it's because swift core members plan on having a value-type equivalent in the near future of NSCache. Same goes for NSPredicate and a few others.

Comment: Any idea why "var flagCache = NSCache<String, UIImage>()" doesn't work due to String not being any object. I thought they Cache keys were always Strings by default...

Comment: @BenSullivan Hi Ben, this works for me:

    let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>();
    
    func setImage(image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        cache.setObject(image, forKey: key as NSString)
    }

Comment: @Donald Thanks for that, I didn't realise it had to be NSString! :)

Comment: let cache = NSCache<String, UIImage>() is not working, but it's ok with NSString. "String doesn't conform to protocol AnyObject...