# Declare a cache in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I'm trying to migrate my app to Swift 3.

How can we declare a cache for UIImage (`NSCache` is now `Cache`)

I have tried using

```
var imageCache: Cache<String, UIImage> = Cache()
```

But the compiler give the error "Use of undeclared type Cache"

How to properly declare a cache in Swift 3?

Comment: Please check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38877474/6541007).

Comment: thanks seem we still need to use NSCache and NSString?

Comment: As for now, it seems to be correct. But keeping `NS`-prefix means that we would have more Swifty version of non-`NS` `Cache`, we may need to wait till then.

Comment: Re why it's `NSCache`, see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md which says "Collection types that are implemented in Foundation are usually generic over objects only and not the `Any` type. We intend to fix this, but the transition will likely also involve these collections becoming a `struct` type themselves. This is related to the 'Specific to Objective-C' rule, as Objective-C collections could only contain objects. Examples: `NSCache`, `NSMapTable`, `NSHashTable`, `NSOrderedSet`."

Answer (score 0):

This works in **Swift 3**

```
var imageCache : NSCache<AnyObject, UIImage>
```